# How many developers can use one iPhone developer key?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

I'm looking to create an iPhone application and will enroll in the [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/apply.html).  However, it isn't clear to me how many developers I can have if I enroll in the Standard Program.  It says the Enterprise Program is for companies with more than 500 developers, so if I work on a team with 2-3 other developers, will the Standard Program work?  Does that just mean all of the applications we create to put into the app store will have the same company info?  What does it take to get each developer enabled to test on their own iPhone?  Is it just a license key that has to be entered?

Comment: Apple has changed the rules for the Enterprise Program. It is now open to any organization with a DUNS number.

Answer (score 14):

1. Two or three developers can easily share a single Developer Certificate, it just needs to be copied to each development machine. The Standard Program should be fine for your purposes.
2. All of the apps you sell on iTunes will be listed under the one company or individual name. If you don't want that, you'll need to open multiple Program accounts.
3. To test on a piece of hardware the code must be signed using a Developer Certificate and a Provisioning Profile which ties the app to the device (by it's UDID number).

The point of code signing is that it identifies the source of the app, so you are free to let employees/partners share a certificate if you are willing to take responsibility for whatever they produce.

Also, Apple uses separate certificates for Development (test as you work) and Distribution (submitting to the store), so sharing the Development Certificate doesn't put your "storefront" at risk.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that when you register with The Standard Program you can do so as an individual or a company (if you are incorporated.)  If you do so as a company, you can have multiple developers on your team, each with their own development certificate.

Comment: You do not have to be incorporated to register as a company.  At a minimum you have to have a "Doing Business As", alternatively you can have an LLC, or be incorporated.  I'm an LLC, and I have 4 developers registered under my standard program.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple developers if you register as a company.  You have three options:

1. Simply apply for a "Doing Business As" from your state clerk
2. Register your company as an LLC, process varies by state, contact your clerk
3. Incorporate your company, this is the most expensive option, and has tax implications

   Next apply for the standard program under that company name.  Remember that this is the name your apps will be released under.

You will be required to mail proof of your company to Apple.  It will take some time for your company to be approved, Apple pays to have a background check done to ensure the company is in fact valid.

Once you are approved you need your other developers to request certificates, here is a link from apple with that process: (requires login)
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

Answer (score -2):

It's quite more complicated than that, you need to get a unique Certificate from Apple for each developer and device (which you can do once you purchase a License). Anyways the bottom line is 1 license = 1 developer + X devices.
So you can register more than one device, buy not more than one developer, so the Standard license will be an odd fit for your needs. So your options are to but a license per developer, or go Enterprise (likely cheaper than several single licenses), or you could have a complicated build setup where a single machine/account does all builds and updates binaries on the devices.

Comment: This is incorrect, 1 license != 1 developer + X devices.  You can have multiple developers if you register as a company, simply apply for a "Doing Business As" from your state clerk and then apply for the standard program under that name.  Remember that this is the name your apps will be released under.

Comment: drye, using the route you recommend, how many developers would be allowed on that license?  Also, would each developer have access to the sensitive information in the account (e.g., credit card info, passwords), or would there be a way to manage that?  Thanks for any clarification you can offer.

Comment: I don't know the limit.  I have five. No, they each use their own apple ID, you just authorize them to develop using your license.