# Iphone developer provisioning

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I had a question concerning developing and testing iPhone app on different Mac laptops. I am currently a registered iphone developer.

I can test using my developer provisioning from which after submitting my Mac private key etc.. so i can test usuing my iPhone and iPod.

So we are a team and we have diff Macbooks, so i wanted to know how to proceed so that the other developer in the team can test using an iPod or Iphone instead of testing using the simulator? I read about sharing private public keys.. but we are not connected in the same network.

Can i simply install my developer provisioning and the other macbook and test using actual device?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install your private key (also copy your public key) that you created the certificate signing request for and the Apple-signed certificate on the other Macs. You can export and later import them in Keychain Access (/Applications/Utilities). You do not need to share a network connection. Of course, you have to install the provisioning profiles for your apps on every device.

I am not sure though, if the individual developers program allows sharing the keys?

Keep in mind that your private key is supposed to stay private. You will be responsible for anything signed with your private key and your name wil appear on the AppStore!

Comment: hello muffix thanks for your response and that really helped me, though i had a question.. my developer program is 99 $ / year so i guess its individual program.

Comment: Hello again muffix, its good i got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805353/how-many-developers-can-use-one-iphone-developer-key :) . thanks again :).